# Handling thread interruptions in a directory iterator

Tags: java, multithreading, file-system, iterator

This code is code written on a whim to help `$someindividual` asking for such a thing on `$somechatmedium`; what is needed is a way, in Java, to provide an `Iterator` over `Path` objects which must only be directories, recursively, and where the number of returned instance number in some sufficient quantities to trigger an `OutOfMemoryError` if eagerly populated.

So, I came up with this (imports omitted for "brevity"):

```
public final class LazyDirectoryIterator
    implements Iterator<Path>, Closeable
{
    private static final int QUEUE_SIZE = 5;
    private static final long TIMEOUT_QUANTITY = 100L;
    private static final TimeUnit TIMEOUT_UNIT = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

    private final ExecutorService executor
        = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final BlockingQueue<Path> queue
        = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);

    private Path nextPath;
    private boolean needNext = true;

    public LazyDirectoryIterator(final Path baseDir)
    {
        executor.submit(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Files.walkFileTree(baseDir, new CustomVisitor());
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        try {
            if (needNext) {
                nextPath = queue.poll(TIMEOUT_QUANTITY, TIMEOUT_UNIT);
                needNext = false;
            }
            return nextPath != null;
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Path next()
    {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        needNext = true;
        return nextPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    private final class CustomVisitor
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
    {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(final Path dir,
            final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            try {
                queue.put(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new IOException("timeout", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are three places here where I purposely choose to set the interrupt flag:

- in the `Runnable` walking the file tree, if I encounter an I/O exception (I'm really not sure about this one; but a `Runnable` can't throw);
- in the `FileVisitor` itself, if I can't push onto the queue;
- in `.hasNext()` if trying and retrieving an element from the queue times out.

It is expected that this Iterator will never run in more than one thread, which is why `needNext` and `nextPath` are not `volatile`. Note that in the three usages above, the two first are in another thread which is spawned from the constructor.

Note: up to Java 7, cannot use Java 8.

So, is my handling of `InterruptedException`s, and my uses of `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` correct?

Answer (score 2):

Overall your code looks fine to me, however some remarks:

1. I would log the `IOExceptions` that may happen during walkFileTree. Otherwise, if there are problems with the tree walk, it's hard to find out the reason later (e.g., if the `baseDir` does not exist). Perhaps you should perform also some sanity checks (i.e, `baseDir` is not null and `baseDir` exists) before submitting the `Runnable`.
2. When catching the `IOException`, it would be also possible to just throw a `RuntimeException` that has the `IOException` as its cause. But this is just a matter of taste. 
   However, in both cases if an `IOException` is thrown you need to be aware that the `ExecutorService` has still an idle thread (that may prevent the shutdown of your app) until you call the `close` method on `LayzDirectoryIterator`. Maybe using a custom `ThreadFactory` that creates daemon threads (and neat thread names) is an option here? I like to use Guava's [ThreadFactoryBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html) for this purpose.
3. I'm generally not a fan of spawning a new Thread within the constructor, I would add an additional start method to submit the tree walk `Runnable`.
4. Your `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` within the `CustomVisitor` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned Java 7. It would be easier if you implemented `AutoCloseable` instead of `Closeable` (see also: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141382/1803692))

> <s>For some reason</s> To preserve backward compatibility language designers decided to create a separate one. This way not only all Closeable classes (like streams throwing IOException) can be used in try-with-resources but also those that wish throwing more general checked exception from close().
>
> When in doubt, use AutoCloseable, users of your class will be grateful.

Just like [s106mo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/57777/s106mo) mentions in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69407/37660) I am also not a fan of spawning a new Thread in your constructor. Unfortunately exactly that is the responsibility of a constructor: getting your class into a working state, that's why I think this solution is the lesser "evil" and would recommend against the start method he proposes.